# How do I differentiate between two WhatsApp messages?

Tags: android, notifications

*First, how did I read WhatsApp messages from notifications?*

Well, I researched and have been able to implement a `NotificationListenerService` with proper permissions(*no underhanded strategies whatsoever*) and listen to notifications messages from WhatsApp. Credit goes to [this guy](http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/08/notificationlistenerservice-and.html) for giving me this idea.

Anyway, I am able to read messages now but the problem is that WhatsApp apparently sends out the same message multiple times sometimes but doesn't display multiple notifications for it. How do I know?

I logged the notification received by my listener and found several identical messages. The general structure of notification looks something like this:

```
StatusBarNotification.toString():

> 10-18 23:43:24.236 16159-16181/com.company D/WhatsApNotifListService:
> StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.whatsapp user=UserHandle{0} id=1
> tag=null score=0 key=0|com.whatsapp|1|null|10170: Notification(pri=0
> contentView=com.whatsapp/0x1090078 vibrate=null sound=null
> defaults=0x0 flags=0x200 color=0xffe65100 category=msg
> groupKey=group_key_messages vis=PRIVATE
> publicVersion=Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.whatsapp/0x1090078
> vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0xffe65100
> category=msg vis=PRIVATE)))
```

`Notification.extras`(A Bundle) structure:

```
> 10-18 23:42:46.199 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.title
> Manish (java.lang.String)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.199 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.subText
> null (null)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.201 16159-16211/com.company D/Util:
> android.car.EXTENSIONS Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=1852]
> (android.os.Bundle)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.201 16159-16211/com.company D/Util:
> android.showChronometer false (java.lang.Boolean)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.icon
> 2130840435 (java.lang.Integer)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.text Bdbdjd
> (java.lang.String)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.progress 0
> (java.lang.Integer)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.progressMax
> 0 (java.lang.Integer)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.showWhen
> true (java.lang.Boolean)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util:
> android.rebuild.applicationInfo ApplicationInfo{1a7615bc com.whatsapp}
> (android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.largeIcon
> android.graphics.Bitmap@a4eb945 (android.graphics.Bitmap)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util: android.infoText
> null (null)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util:
> android.wearable.EXTENSIONS Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=668]
> (android.os.Bundle)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util:
> android.originatingUserId 0 (java.lang.Integer)
> 
> 10-18 23:42:46.202 16159-16211/com.company D/Util:
> android.progressIndeterminate false (java.lang.Boolean)
```

Is there any way like Id or something that can be extracted to differentiate two messages?

Comment: Maybe you can store previous messages and check wether they exists. If they are not equal you can clear the message cache, and replace it with the last known message? It's unlikely that a person sends the same message multiple times. I am just saying the idea, it might not fit your needs.

Comment: After extracting the messages where do you keep them?

Comment: Do you show them in a view or you keep them somewhere?

Comment: @Xenolion : An ArrayList(cache) as well as SQLite

Comment: @Xenolion : I show them in a RecyclerView from the ArrayList

Comment: Why dont you use time as a way to show that a message is already taken!

Comment: @Xenolion : Time that I extracted from `notification.when` is also same. The messages seem to be identical. My guess is that the Intent used for the notification has extras that has some differentiating factor but that's impossible to extract from PendingIntent(I researched on that)

Comment: I think you should use a content provider for your app sqlite database implement a loader and check your message when adding to the database using an appropriate sqlite clause to differentiate the messages. I have said a loader because any change in the database is completely loaded throughout your app. And so no need for arraylist cache.

Comment: Oh should I answer? To add more details on that!

Comment: @Xenolion : Well, I could do that as an overall improvement to the flow but the fundamental problem would remain, i.e, distinguishable. If you have some snippet to copy from for your proposed solution, it would be appreciated though.

Comment: @Xenolion : Problem solved. Your suggestion of time worked. The time I had extracted from the timestamp was formatted and therefore wasn't accurate. For two identical messages, time is identical too. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh I am glad that worked. But since it you have answered the question  I guess you cant accept it Today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I solved my problem. The timestamp was the answer. Credit goes to @xenolion for suggesting time. My mind had preconceived notion about time being different but I just checked the timestamp of the messages and the identical messages have the same timestamp.

Comment: **Happy  Coding!**